# Autoit:How to select certain words from within a paragraph of text

Tags: autoit

### I need to automate a task wherein out of paragraph of text i need to select specific  lines for example in below paragraph:

About Us:
Hello! It's nice of you to take the time to get to know us better. Here are some things about us. 
founded by 2015 as . since then  serving thousands of customer all over india with quality products and services.

About the product :
**Brand : JK Perfume
Leave no stains on cloths, Intense yet hardly overwhelming, Perfumes are distilled to provide a light and relaxing feel with a tinge of freshness due to the citrus fragrance. 
Size : 100ml Liquid Filled In Beautiful Glass Bottle. Ideal for Gifting.**

Shipping :
For Safe and Quick delivery of products, we ship only through Fedex. Fedex covers almost all the pincodes.

Support :
In case you have any query or conern regarding our Product or Services  you can email us or call us

---

In the above paragraph, i need to select Words situated between "About the product" and "Shipping" (Words marked in bold"

Now the words to select may increase or decrease for n number of records but they will always be in between what i have mentioned above.
How to use Autoit to select this?

Answer (score 1):

Put the text into a variable and then use the function : _StringBetween